# Why would purge in development affect production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I purged a bunch of attachments in development, and it deleted all of them from production.  For example, User.find(1).avatar.purge removed the attached avatar in development, but also removed the file from S3. So, now the associated record in production has a broken img.

confirmed (just to be sure) that Rails.env does return development.

I confirmed storage.yml local is:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

development.rb has:

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Is there a setting or something I missed?  Why would this happen?

Comment: Can you share what command(s) you ran exactly? Or what steps you did exactly.

Comment: I simply called purge on various records.  For example User.find(1).avatar.purge removed the attached avatar in development, but also removed the file from S3.  So, now the associated record in production has a broken img.

Comment: It sounds like you have development and production using the same bucket?  I see your edits to the question, but what buckets are being set for the different `envs`?  Can you verify that production and development are using different buckets? I assume they are not using the same DB credentials.

Comment: I thought that too.  I double checked my buckets.  In storage.yml, local defines local storage (see question) and amazon which includes defining the bucket.  Development.rb sets active_storage.service to local, and production.rb sets active_storage.service to amazon.  .env does define an S3_BUCKET for development and I confirmed ENV['S3_BUCKET'] is pulling from my local .env.  Very odd.  There's a disconnect somewhere...

Comment: That being said...the development bucket should not even be in play since development.rb is set for local storage.

Comment: Sometimes I pull in the production database using pg:pull.  This gives me access to a complete data set.  In an ActiveStorage::Blob there is a column for :service_name.  Since the image was originally attached in production, and I am now running purge in development...active storage must be reading the service_name and using the credentials for that service.  I guess that makes sense.  But, what if I want to manipulate existing data that is now actually in my development env?

Comment: Ya somewhere along the line the env is getting switched to production it sounds like,  so you are hitting that bucket  Not really anyway to tell, I have one app where I did this for a little bit and one trick I learned was I output `<%= Rails.env %>` in all my views so I always had a reminder.  Might try that to see what env the app, locally, is actually running in, is it possible you are setting the env to production via something like `rails s -e production` or similar? You could also try outputting some other env variable, like a bucket name or something to test as well.

Comment: I did check Rails.env and it is dev. I also put an ENV[] and the environment is pulling from the local .env file. I don’t think it’s related to Amy of that. The service_name column corresponds to whatever services I defined in storage.yml.  I think rails is reading the service_name in the blob and loading that service...regardless of the environment or environment setting. This seems like bug.  Unfortunately, the docs in this new column are lacking. I’m gonna submit a bug report in rails.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a bug in Rails, although it is a bit unexpected.  I submitted an issue for this and got a great response.  Basically, the way to proceed to is to name each bucket using Rails.env.  That way, when calling purge in dev AS won't find the image.  Seems odd that Rails would have this loose end.  But, for now...it does.

issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42186